# Command fails in script, works in command line

Tags: mongodb, command-line

I have a simple script to get an export from MongoDB:

```
#!/bin/sh -x

QUERY="'{ \"type\":\"listing\" }'"

mongoexport --db event --collection listing --query $QUERY --fields type,name --csv
```

(I'm using the -x switch for debugging purposes)

Here's the output when I run the script:

```
$ ./simple_query.sh 
+ QUERY='{ "type":"listing" }'
+ mongoexport --db event --collection listing --query '{ "type":"listing" }' --fields type,name --csv
ERROR: too many positional options
```

However, if I merely copy and paste the mongoexport line to the prompt, it works!  What's going on?

(Using MongoDB 2.0.0)

Comment: Should `--fields "type","name"` be `--fields "type,name"`?

Comment: In fact, looking at the docs I don't think it should have quotes at all: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongoexport

Comment: Good thought, but doesn't fix the problem.  On the command line, both quoted field names and unquoted ones work.  In a script, neither way works.  Edited out the quotes in this question for simplicity's sake.

Comment: And you've confirmed that it is the `'{ "type":"listing" }'` that is causing the problem by removing it from the script? Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using older version of mongodb? If so maybe it's [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3238) bug. It is fixed on 2.0.0-* versions.

**Edit**: Actually this might be different problem. You can fix it by removing the spaces on the query. Spaces seem to make the shell think it is actually multiple arguments:

```
QUERY="'{\"type\":\"listing\"}'"
```

Comment: @raphaelcm Just realized the problem can be solved by removing the spaces. Answer edited.

Comment: Ok that works...seems strange though.  Shouldn't mongoexport be able to handle spaces in a quoted string?